# Mixed languages in umbraco backend

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have an umbraco installation with mixed languages in the backend. When I switch the language for my user to "English (United Kingdom)" or "English (USA)" I still see some german words in the backend, e.g. "Durchsuchen" instead of "Type to search..." in the search box or "Entwickler" instead of "Developer", but not everywhere as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

The default ui language is set to "EN"

```
<add key="umbracoDefaultUILanguage" value="en" />
```

Any tips or hints how to fix this?

**Update**:

Looking through `packages.config` I saw that these additional packages were installed:

- [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.de](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.de)
- [Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.de](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.de/)
- [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.de](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.de/)

I uninstalled them via nuget console, cleared the cache, removed *App_Data*, *bin* and *obj* and cleaned the project, but that still didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the server and app pool then remove App_Data and then start app pool and server again? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: That's a really weird issue!

Comment: Is it happening for all users that login to the CMS? If not, maybe try to change the language to something else for the user account you are using and then change it back to English. I'll be interested to know the solution to this haha

Comment: It happens for all users, no matter what OS (Macos/Windows) and no matter what browser (Chrome/Safari/Firefox).

Comment: Did you try the simple way to clearing the cache? for the short way try ctrl+shift+R together.

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Even when you access the page from a "clen" computer you still see this setup :(

Comment: I would try asking this same question over at our.umbraco.org - or even report it as a bug on http://issues.umbraco.org/dashboard as it sure does seem like a bug :-s

Comment: Already asked over at our.umbraco.org: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started//82363-mixed-languages-in-umbraco-backend
I don't want to report a bug without knowing how to reproduce it :( We have other umbraco installations here where this doesn't happen.

Comment: Fair enough :-) Hope you find a solution!

Comment: I would try downloading a fresh zip of your version of umbraco and doing some sort of comparison on the files. I like to use BeyondCompare. Maybe you'll notice something missing or mismatched in your `/umbraco` directory or in your `/config/Lang` directory. Was your site recently upgraded?

Comment: @bowserm I compared it with a "working" umbraco instance from another project and couldn't find any differences. Maybe will try it with a clean zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the reason for this really weird behaviour, so I went for a pragmatic solution: I replaced `Umbraco\config\lang\de.xml` with `Umbraco\config\lang\en.xml` and adjusted the attributes in the `language` element.

Now all german user see the backend completely in English, but that's not so annoying as for english user to see a mixed german-english backend.